# Activating two labels with one click

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-selectors

I'm trying to use the "checkbox hack" for a tab group design.
clicking on one tab (label) checks a radio box. Then using a ~ selector i can switch the pages between display: block/none;

To illustrate this setup, there's first a row of tab buttons and then a row of pages. The radio boxes live as siblings in the pages container.

```
+-------------------+
| +------+ +------+ |
| | tab1 | | tab2 | |
| +------+ +------+ |
+-------------------+
| +---------------+ |
| |     page 1    | |
| +---------------+ |
| +---------------+ |
| |     page 2    | |
| +---------------+ |
+-------------------+
```

This primary feature is working, the pages swap out as expected.

Now for the next part, where im having trouble...

When u click a tab i need to change it's css to look "selected". Since the radio boxes are in the pages container I cant use them and a sibling selector to style the tabs themself. It seems that I need another set of radio buttons, this time within the tabs container.

I've gotten this second "checkbox hack" to work, but now I can't seem to execute the two features at the same time. 
The tab's are built like:

```
<label for='tab_selector_1'>
    <input id='tab_selector_1' type='radio'/>
    <label for='page_selector_1' id='tab_1'>TAB NAME</label>
</label>
```

I'd expected the click to bubble through the two labels and activate both checkboxes, but it only acts on the deepest label. In this case only switching the page and not the tab style.

Is there some way to restructure this, or use different css selectors to make it work? The html can be all changed around if this is a bad way to be going about it, I just need it to be a non-js solution.

DEMO: https://codepen.io/sammurphey/pen/RebNYo

Comment: Do you have this in a Codepen or Codesandbox? Due to the nature of what you are trying to do, this is probably going to take some trial and error to see if there's a pure html/css solution. Technically using the :focus pesudo class would work, but that will only work until focus moves elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: @brianespinosa thanks, i've just added the codepen, see edit

Comment: A quick Google for `pure css tabs` yielded [this](https://codepen.io/renatorib/pen/rlpfj). Is that not what you're after?

Comment: @fubar u come off kinda harsh here, i was obviously just making too overly specific searches. But yes that will do, thank you for showing it to me.

Comment: @fubar if u'll just post that link as an answer ill mark it accepted n close this thing out

Comment: @SamMurphey, that fair, it was an abrupt comment. Glad the link helps.

Answer (score 0):

## `<input type="radio">` High and Hidden

Place your radio buttons at a higher level than the the elements you wish to toggle styles on and  assign them `display:none`.

### Example

> ```
> <form>
>     <input id='tab0' type='radio'> <!--#tab0 ~ fieldset > legend > [for=tab0] -->
>     <input id='tab1' type='radio'> <!--#tab1 + fieldset > legend > [for=tab1] -->
>       <fieldset>
>          <legend>
>             <label for='tab0'>Page 0</label>
>             <label for='tab1'>Page 1</label>
>          </legend>
> ```

**Note:** That you only need one `<label>` and one `<input>` to style a tab and its corresponding page. Posted is a fully functional demo of this pattern and a link to a fork of refactored OP code.

---

#### [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/01/pen/pxzgJd?editors=1100)

### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100&;
  height: 100%;
}

.tab {
  display: none
}

.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tabs label {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.tabs label:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#tab0:checked~fieldset .tabs>[for=tab0],
#tab1:checked+fieldset>.tabs>[for=tab1] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.page {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#tab0:checked~fieldset>#page0,
#tab1:checked+fieldset>#page1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <form id='ui'>


    <input id='tab0' class='tab' name='tab' type='radio' checked='true'>
    <input id='tab1' class='tab' name='tab' type='radio'>

    <fieldset>
      <legend class="tabs">
        <label for='tab0' class='btn'>Page 0</label>
        <label for='tab1' class='btn'>Page 1</label>
      </legend>
      <section id='page0' class='page'>
        <article>
          <h1>Page 0 Content</h1>
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>
      </section>

      <section id='page1' class='page'>
        <article>
          <h1>Page 1 Content</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </article>
      </section>


    </fieldset>
  </form>

</main>
```